# jquery duplicate nodes matching and removing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 nodesets that have the following contents;

```
obj1 "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>"
obj2 "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox </p>"
```

I am attempting to match the contents of obj1 with obj2 and then remove the matched nodes to leave behind an object that looks like.

```
output "<p>jumped over the fence</p>"
```

Using jquery $.match returns an error and $.find yields no results either, is there any other effective method of doing what I am trying to work out?

Comment: What do you want to see when obj1 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>" and obj2 ="<p>the quick <b>green</b> fox </p>"

Comment: i want to take obj1 and compare obj2 against it... and remove the duplication to form the output i have asked for

Comment: Are you trying to compare html inside the <p> tags, or any html in general. because notice how the <p> tag match but isn't removed, yet the <b> tags match and are remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this fits the requirements, but the variables looks like HTML strings to me, and it looks like you want to compare the string word by word whitout loosing the original main element, and I would do something like:

```
var obj1 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>",
    obj2 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox </p>";

var obj3 = compare(obj1, obj2);

$('body').append(obj3);


function compare(elm1, elm2) {
    var obj = [],
        o1 = String($(elm1).html()).split(' '), //get <p>'s inner HTML as string and split on spaces to get each word
        o2 = String($(elm2).html()).split(' ');

    $.each(o1, function(i,e) { //iterate over each word inside <p> of first string
        if (e !== o2[i]) obj.push(e); //check if matches each word in the same loaction in the second string
    });
    //we should now have an array of the words that does not match each other
    return $(elm1).clone().html(obj.join(' ')); //join with new spaces and return the string as html contained in a clone of the original element.
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8WNP/)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8WNP/2/) as a function to call (seems simpler) !

Should add that this won't work for something like :

```
var obj1 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>",
    obj2 = "<p>fox jumped over the fence</p>";
```

as those strings does not word for word match, all though the second is part of the first etc. but to remove the similar parts of the string in such an event you could always just do :

```
var obj1 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>",
    obj2 = "<p>fox jumped over the</p>",
    o1 = String($(obj1).html()),
    o2 = String($(obj2).html());

var obj = $(obj1).clone().html(o1.replace(o2, ''));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8WNP/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick stab at it.  Maybe this helps. It will leave the bold tag in the HTML and might not cover anything outside your direct question.

```
var obj1 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox jumped over the fence</p>";
var obj2 = "<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox </p>";

var result="";
var inTag=false;

for (i=0;i<obj1.length;i++)
{
    if(obj1[i]=='<')
        isTag=true;
    if(!isTag)
    {
        if(i<obj2.length-1)
        {
            if(obj1[i]!=obj2[i])
            {
                result+=obj1[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result+=obj1[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result+=obj1[i];
    }
    if(obj1[i]=='>')
        isTag=false;
}

$("#result").html(obj1+obj2 + "<p>Difference:</p>"+result);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qYV4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var obj1Txt= $(obj1).text();
var obj2txt= $(obj2).text();
var output= '<p>'+obj1txt.replace(obj2txt,'')+'</p>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to match the string representations using $.html()

```
return obj1.clone().html(obj1.html().replace(obj2.html(), ''))
```

Comment: Does not really work, obj2.html outputs `<p>the quick <b>brown</b> fox </p>` -> the first <p> is not matched, and so the whole replacement does not work.

Comment: I thought obj1 and obj2 were jQuery objects. Regardless, `$(obj1).clone().html($(obj1).html().replace($(obj2).html(), ''))` should work